# Server Error in '/' Application. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, reference, set, instance, server-error

I've been trying to figure it out but not getting it.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) +662
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +74
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are using VS2019, make sure to uncheck Enable Browser Link
[VSCode EnableBroswerLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlU6n.png)

Comment: Thanks you so much. I have been debugging this since last 3 hours

Comment: Spent hours on this issue until I found out this answer. Just adding it still works for VS2022.